# Packing space by cones: Translates best?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, open-problems, packing-and-covering, circle-packing

Let $C$ be a right circular cone, the convex hull of a unit-radius disk
and a point directly above the disk center at height $h$.

---

[image]

---

> Is the most dense packing of $\mathbb{R}^3$ achieved by translates
>   of $C$ and its negative,<sup>*</sup> $-C$, i.e., upside-down $C$?
>   Or is it known that rotations of the cones permit achieving a denser packing?

<sup>*</sup>
<sub>Barany, Imre, and Jiri Matousek. "Packing cones and their negatives in space." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 38.2 (2007): 177-187. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-007-1332-9#page-1))</sub>

---

Here is *TMA*'s idea:

           
[image: PackingCones]

---

(*27Jun14*).
Conjecture by  Wlodek Kuperberg (see the comments), *the* expert on the topic:

> "For a generic cone,
>   the densest packing by translates of the cone and its point-reflection
>   is perhaps the best one."

Now marked as an open problem.

Comment: I see it as dependent on the ratio radius/height. For example, pack 6 cones point to point inside a cube.

Comment: In the above, r=h and the density is pi/4.

Comment: Direct link to the article on the website of one of the authors: http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/kuper.pdf

Comment: If one does a "penny packing" of cones (bases in a hexagonal lattice), with a negative on top to fill space, I get a density of (2/3)(pi/2sqrt(3)) or pi/sqrt(27) density, regardless of h. So there is an open interval around 1 of values of r/h in which cube-packing gives a higher density. There may also be a good packing based on a tesellation by octahedra and tetrahedra, but I am not seeing it yet.

Comment: It's also possible coding theory might give some good packings of cones inside a sphere, but what would actually be packed are certain truncations of a sphere, and I do not see how to calculate the density of a "golf ball" packing.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger The "penny packing" has substantial room for local improvement, since the opposing layers don't touch.

Comment: @S.Carnahan, I would like to see a specific packing that does so.  The version I had in mind had translates of an infinite line of cones and their negatives, tip touching base circumference.  If you can squeeze one cone in between two such lines or give a nicely described denser packing, I would welcome it.

Comment: The best packing density of a cone most likely depends on its shape, that is, the ratio between its height and the diameter of its base. For a generic cone, the densest packing by translates of the cone and its point-reflection is perhaps the best one - this is a conjecture. Here is a relevant reference: Bezdek, A., Kuperberg, W.: *Dense packing of space with various convex solids*, L. Fejes Toth Special Volume, Renyi Inst., Hungary, 2010; http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.2398.pdf