# How many cones with angle theta can I pack into the unit sphere?

Tags: sphere-packing, cones

Given a unit sphere (radius 1), I would like to know how many cones I can pack into this unit sphere. Restrictions: The top of the cone needs to be in the center of origin. The bottom of the cone needs to form a circle on the unit sphere.

I have found a related question, but with a cube: [Packing space by cones: Translates best?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171803/packing-space-by-cones-translates-best)

I have also tried to find an upper bound myself by performing the following calculation: 
Surface of the projection of the base of the cone on the unit sphere:
$$2 \pi r^2(1 + \sin(\theta) \pm \cos(\theta))$$

Surface of the unit sphere: $4 \pi r^2$

Now, a (very high) upper bound would be:

$$\frac{2 \pi r^2(1 + \sin(\theta) \pm \cos(\theta))}{4 \pi r^2}$$

This however does not take into account the restrictions of the shapes, so the actual number will likely be much lower.

Question 1: What would be a closer upper bound 
Question 2: If an example value is easier, what would be a realistic number of cones given $\theta = 5^{\circ}$

Comment: If $\theta$ becomes small, the curvature of the sphere becomes less important. So asymptotically for $\theta\rightarrow 0$ you get your upper bound multiplied by the sphere packing constant. However, I don't understand your formula for the area of the base, neither typographically nor mathematically. It does not seem to scale with $\theta^2$ for small $theta$ as it should.

Comment: Seems to me that $\theta$ should be listed in the restrictions. You shouldn't rely on the title of the question for relaying crucial parts of the questions.

Answer (score 7):

This is the problem of finding [spherical codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_code). Putatively optimal solutions can be found at [Neil Sloane's website](http://neilsloane.com/packings/).

For an [upper bound](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html), there's $d\leq\sqrt{4-csc^2[\frac{πn}{6(n-2)}]}$, where $d$ is the 3d distance  between some two points.

Answer (score 4):

A good reference for volumetric arguments for the maximum number of 'cones' or spherical 'caps'  that one can fit, is a series of [papers](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9d22/31a625917592cf6f4b6c4a239c2ef22d1386.pdf) by Jon Hamkins. The density of a packing of these caps can be at most $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$, (this being known as the  Fejes Tóth bound) and in the minimal distance between centers of a packing, $d$, the density is bounded above by $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}-O(d^2)$.

This follows from a bound on the maximum size of a code on the sphere with pairwise distances at least $d$,

$$M(3,d)\leq 2\left(1-\frac{\pi}{6\cot^{-1}\sqrt{3-d^2}}\right)^{-1}$$

taken from chapter three of Hamkin's thesis [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.97&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (being another form of Tóth's bound).

For specific parameters, the problem can be pretty intricate. One of the best references has already been mentioned in Bullet's answer and is Sloane's [webpage](http://neilsloane.com/packings/). Codes on Euclidean Spheres, by Ericson and Zinoviev is worth checking out as well as a reference on these specific packings (and is slightly outdated), along with Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups by Conway and Sloane.